# stringVar.data.toString().replace("", "") equivalent in swift

Tags: swift, string, kotlin, replace

I have json objects that the object strings value needs to change. Not the property name itself, but the value of it.

example json :  "jsonObject" : "SomeValue"

I want to replace "someValue" with an empty string for now. However I have 15 or more jsonObjects to do this with.

I have the method in Kotlin, but am unsure of its Swift counterpart. in Swift, I know I can use .replacingOccurences(of: "", with: "") , but I don't think this solves my issue, perhaps?

Kotlin Code :

```
private fun parseGetDeviceDataResponse(data: ByteArray): String {

    var msg = ""

    try {
        msg = data.toString(Charsets.UTF_8).replace("\\n", "")
        val msgJSON = Json(msg)
        val objJSON = msgJSON.obj()
        objJSON.put("jsonObject1", "")
        objJSON.put("jsonObject2", "")

        msg = objJSON.toString()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        msg = e.toString()
    }
    return msg
}
```

So, basically, what's the Swift equivalent here?

Comment: What's wrong with `replacingOccurences`?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with it, I think Im trying to cheat and not have to use it for every single json object. that would be 17 lines of code for replacingOccurances. Blah!

Answer (score 0):

```
replace("\\n", "")
```

If you need just to remove new lines you can use:

```
aString.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.newlines)
```

Comment: `trimmingCharacters` only removes the matching characters from either end of the string, not from the middle.